# Custom Field For Login

Tags: login, wp-login-form

I have managed to create a plugin which creates a unique number on registration. However, now it comes to having the player login into their front end control panel. So far I am using the following as an example:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <div>
        Player id: <input name="log" type="text" />
    </div>
    <div>
        Password: <input name="pwd" type="password" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Login" />
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="my_login_action" />
    </div>
</form>
```

How do I login with only the player ID and password?

I don't want to login with email or username. Bare in mind, this is for a front end dashboard as well, so I think I'm using the wrong code:

```
add_action( 'init', function() {    
    // Not the login request?
    if ( ! isset( $_POST['action'] ) || $_POST['action'] !== 'my_login_action' )
        return;

    // See the Codex for wp_signon()
    $result = wp_signon();

    if ( is_wp_error( $result ) )
        wp_die( 'Login failed. Wrong password or user name?' );

    // Redirect back to the requested page if login was successful    
    header( 'Location: ' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] );
    exit;
} );
```

Comment: I'd guess that you would need to do a user query for the user with matching player ID, then use the resulting username with the password to log them in.

Comment: @Milo and others I found a really need plugin that does what I need http://www.admincolumns.com/documentation/